# What is the correct way of returning a file in a Rest webservice request?

Tags: web-services, file, rest

I need to return a file in my webservice. I am bit in doubt of what is the best/correct/execpted way. (I am using JSON).

I can:

1. simply return the file (as normal download) with the correct mime type, etc. via HTTP
2. encode de file (eg: Base64 or other) and send it inside the JSON answer
3. return a json answer with the url where the file can be found.

Comment: The second one will require more download time, and the third one will require two requests (so additional latency). But all 3 are valid...  Can you say a little more about your needs?

Comment: @Aurélien yes, I am aware of that. But for now I am more interested in the "formal correction" than in the size. That will be a second step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are valid, depending on the client's needs, so why not make it the client's choice?

Let's say it's an `image/jpeg` file:

If the client sent the `Accept: image/jpeg` header, you return the file as a normal download.

If the client sent the `Accept: image/jpeg` header and the `Accept-Encoding: base64`, you return it as a normal download, Base64 encoded.

If the client sends the `Accept: text/uri-list` header, you return a plain text response with the URI for the image stored somewhere else.

There are no standard mimetypes to return base64 or links inside json, but you can use some standard of your own and create a vnd mimetype, as long as you document it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is a good idea. What would you do if the client sends the default text/html?

Comment: That depends on your application. You can return a human readable representation of the resource, or you can return HTML documentation for that part of the API, or you can return `406 Not Acceptable` if it doesn't make sense to request `text/html` for that resource. Keep in mind that the "default" isn't `text/html`, but `*`, which means accept everything. The server determines the default, not the client.